# What CSS should I use to create a series of horizontal, non-wrapping blocks?

Tags: css, horizontal-scrolling

I have a set of dynamically generated content - anywhere between 1 and about 25 blocks (each of which I want to be about 250px wide.

Clearly, this can run off-screen, but that's fine since my design allows for horizontal scrolling (using jQuery - I don't want the browser to do it with its own scroll bars).

So what CSS - cross-browser - is the best approach? Floats seem to wrap unreliably, and the dynamic nature of the content which changes frequently through ajax calls - means that recalculating the container width is not very practical.

Other CSS-based option?

Comment: Won´t you be recalculating the width of the container anyway in order for your horizontal jQuery scrolling to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a div container with the absolute witdh set, allow overlow, and floats for each box. This will allow the boxes overflow off the right of the screen.

Comment: This is how I went. It meant the additional step of calculating the width (since the number of boxes can change), but there didn't seem a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
#container { 
  overflow-x: auto; 
  white-space: nowrap; 

  width: XXXpx; height: XXXpx;
}
#container .block { 
  float: left; 
}
```

The `overflow-x` setting will ensure a scrollbar if the content extends beyond the width, the `white-space` setting will ensure all content is on one line.

Answer (score 0):

Other than floats? Tables :D
Seriously, use floats.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567395/force-elements-to-be-horizontally-aligned/15567586#15567586)

Why not use single row table, in spite of standards?

Because if you won't make the container element fixed width, all those whitespace and inline-block elements won't work, so the contents will wrap as well. And if I don't know actual width of the gallery (which I can't know, as far as content is added dynamically), I cannot specify it's width like that.