# Force elements to be horizontally aligned

Tags: css, horizontal-scrolling

Let's say I have random children in my div, which has fixed height and width set to 100% to breathe with the layout.

Which CSS must I use to force child elements to align horizontally and when the div's width is smaller then the content, display a scrollbar and not overlap one another?

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/GRBc6/1/

simple css:

```
.parent{
    width:500px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}
.kid{
    width: 150px;
    height: 20px;
     background-color: green;
    float:left;
    margin-left:4px; 
}
```

Comment: float:left ? overflow-x: scroll ?

Comment: You can try in the fiddle above it doesn't work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

if you make the kid an `inline-block` element and take off the `float:left`, you can make the parent have `white-space:nowrap` and it will achieve what you want:

```
.parent{
    width:300px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow-x:scroll;
}
.kid{
    width: 150px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: green;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:4px;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GRBc6/6/

Comment: It works perfects. Thank you! I was missing this: white-space:nowrap;

Answer (score 0):

You need to add 2 properties to `.parent`: `overflow-x:scroll` and `white-space:nowrap`, and change the `float` property of kids to `display: inline-block`. Here's working code:

```
.parent{
    width:500px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red; 
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.kid{
    width: 150px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: green;
    margin-left:4px; 
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

or otherwise you could just use table with a single row, **tr** → **td** 
So it won't let the elements inside it wrap

Comment: Tables are for tabular data

Comment: it is ok to use this way if the container div isn't fixed

Comment: I guess you're not bothered about coding standards then http://www.w3.org/WAI/wcag-curric/sam48-0.htm

Comment: I was worried more about how to make horizontal gallery with non-fixed width via css, but couldn't figure it out. can you propose any solution for that?

Comment: Because if you won't make the container element fixed width, all those whitespace and inline-block elements won't work, so the contents will wrap as well. And if I don't know actual width of the gallery (which I can't know, as far as content is added dynamically), you cannot specify it's width like that.

Comment: you can just set the width of the parent container as 100% and use the above styles to make the content have a horizontal scroller if the number of boxes is greater than 100% width

Comment: but won't it look like an iframe, adding extra scroll. The point was to make the whole page horizontal, no matter what width it will have